# How do I use MySQL as a back-end designer on Windows 7

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have used MySQL in the past but it was always in the capacity of a front-end developer accessing the MySQL database through a web hosting provider and if I altered, or created a database, it was always through the online tools offered by the online host.

I want to create a mysql database locally on my windows 7 pc.

I have done all the set-up steps I think are necessary.  I have downloaded mysql-installer-community-5.6.22.0 from the MySql web site and I ran it to install MySQL.  I chose to install everything.

I looked at all that was installed but I did not find what tool I needed.  I thought that the MySql Workbench 6.2 CE would help but I did not find an option to create a new database or tables.  I noticed that there is a command line client but I am not sure the syntax I should use.

I would like to use a good GUI to create a couple of test databases and tables.

Comment: Workbench is exactly the GUI tool you use to make databases and tables and such. I think Workbench calles databases Schemas though, so look for those. The first step is to start the server which you can do from the command line using the `mysqld` program/command that you downloaded with MySQL.

Comment: @Takendarkk I believe that when mysql is installed on Windows it creates a service that start the mysql server at time of install and will start mysql server automatically on reboot unless the user configures it otherwise.

Comment: @Tajendarjj You are right that databases are called schemas in the workbench.  This threw me off.  I have been experimenting with the workbench and I have a new batch of questions now.  When I create a new tale, it asks for an Engine (InnoDB, MyIsam...).  WHat is that?  Also there are check boxes for the columns: PK NM, UQ, BIN, UN, ZF, AI. What are those?  Much thanks.

Comment: I guess PK is primary key.  What is NN, UN and AI?

Comment: NN == Not Null; UQ == Unique, BIN == Binary, UN == Unsigned, zf == Zero fill, AI is auto increment.  There are corresponding check boxes at the bottom of the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of free and paid GUI's that you can use to interact with Mysql.

[Mysql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

[Dbforge](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/)

[Toad](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/default.aspx?Redirected=true)

[Sqlyog](https://www.webyog.com/)

Which tool is best suited for your environment really depends on what you are trying to do with your Mysql database(s).

As for Mysql Workbench, when you open it the initial screen that is displayed will have no connections.  You will first have to establish a connection to your localhost in order to create databases and tables.

You could also use the command line client. When you open it, it will ask you for your password to your localhost. Once entered, you can [create databases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) and [create tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

In the future when in doubt just go to [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html)